# How to set an array inside $_SESSION in Laravel 5?

Tags: session, laravel-5

I have this code:

```
Session::set('dt[global][temp][arrLanguage_selector]', $arrLanguage_selector);
```

and

```
Session::set('dt[global][env][country]', $country);
```

Later in others page I will try to get these values back with:

```
$global = Session::get('dt[global]');
$env= $global[env][country]ç
$lang = [temp][arrLanguage_selector];
```

But it is not working. It is returning `null`

What am I missing?

Comment: Is $country an array()?

Comment: no, it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution:

If We want to create the follow array structure inside the **$_SESSION**.

```
$dt = [
        "globals"  =>[
                        "env"         =>"US",
                        "dictionary"  =>$arrDictionary
                      ],

        "temp"     =>[
                         "arrLanguage_selector"=>$arrLanguage_selector,
                         "other_thing          =>"ok"                     
                      ]
      ];
```

We can do it in one shot:

1. `Session::put('dt.globals.env','US');`
2. `Session::put('dt.globals.dictionary',$arrDictionary);`
3. `Session::put('dt.temp.arrLanguage_selector',$arrLanguage_selector);`
4. `Session::put('dt.temp.other_thing',"ok");`
5. Make `dd(Session::all());` to display.

Or we can create or change on the fly:

1. `Session::put('dt.globals.env','CA');`
2. `Session::put('dt.globals.subLevel','subZero');`
3. Make `dd(Session::all());` to display.

Note:
The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session) was not so clear.